# WebFiguresService is not showing output in Matlab-.NET deployment

Tags: c#, asp.net, matlab, matlab-deployment

I have created a web application and I have used `webfigureservice` to add MATLAB figures to my ASP.NET web application. 
Although, I am getting the symbol of webfigure service on webpage but it is not displaying graph.
As I have done this thing earlier and in my earlier project,by add reference I found that it's path was `GAC_32` folder but now I forgot how I did.

Now I am trying to add `webfigureservice.dll` in `GAC` folder, I am unable to access that folder.
Please tell me the simple line by line method to follow and get that graph or reference should be of `webfigureservice.dll` in assembly.